# how to install python packages for brew installed pythons

Tags: python, homebrew

I just finished installing the latest stable version of python via Homebrew.

$ brew install python3

Everything works fine. I would like to install packages, for example PyMongo. 
I don't have pip.

$ pip
-bash: pip: command not found

and there is no Homebrew formulae for it:

$ brew install PyMongo

brew install PyMongo
Error: No available formula for pymongo
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...

Any idea what's the best way to install PyMongo on OS X when Python was installed via Homebrew. Thank you!

Comment: How about installing `pip` via `homebrew` and then installing `pymongo` via `pip`?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if this is the best way but I managed to install it with: 
$ python3 -m easy_install pymongo

Answer (score 13):

Use `pip3`. The "caveats" text you see when you run `brew info python3` was printed for you after python3 was installed; that text is frequently helpful! It reads:

> You can install Python packages with
>
> pip3 install <package>
>
> They will install into the site-package directory
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages